# Does graph traversal require stack machine?

Tags: finite-automata, graph-traversal, stacks

I'm writing a graph traversal function to be used in a garbage collector.

To avoid stack overflow, I used a finite state machine. Roughly, it descends into child nodes recursively to mark objects, and return to root (to descent down again) whenever a branch is exshausted.

However, I realized that if there's loop in the graph, it cannot handle it, as it cannot distinguish a node marked for traversal in its children/descendents from a node that it had visited before.

Q: Does traversal on a graph with loop require a stack machine? If so, I'll rewrite my traversal function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as it cannot distinguish a node marked for traversal in its children/descendents from a node that it had visited before.

This can be fixed by traversing a list of nodes it's visiting, starting from root - this list doesn't have to be stored, restarting from root and iterating forward is sufficient; when a node found matching the one it's about to descend into, the function retracts.

Hence, it doesn't require a stack. But again, such implementation is very complex to implement and comprehend, and quite inefficient.